# hook_library not getting called

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript

I am trying to implement hook_library in my custom module.  To help narrow down the problem, I wrote a dummy module with just the following two functions:  hook_views_api and hook_library.  I put a dsm statement in each of the hooks, to test whether the hook was getting executed.  The hook_views_api hook is getting executed but not the hook_library hook.  Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I have tried clearing the cache.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module.

Here is the code:

```
// hook_views_api
function mymodule_views_api() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/views';
  dsm ("inside mymodule_views_api");
  return array(
    'api' => 2,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/views',
  );
} 

// hook_library
function mymodule_library(){
  dsm ("inside mymodule_library");
  return array();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using watchdog() instead of dsm()?

Comment: I just tried using watchdog() instead, and I am having the same problem:  the hook_library watchdog message does not show up in the log, i.e. it still seems hook_library is not getting executed.

Comment: I am now wondering ... perhaps hook_library does not get executed until it is needed, i.e. until the first call to drupal_add_library.  I will test this and report back ...

Comment: OK, remember to clear drupal cache, e.g admin > performance > clear all caches

Comment: Problem solved!  I added a call to drupal_add_library(), and hook_library now gets executed.  So it seems hook_library is not executed until it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [only function that invokes `hook_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/invokes/hook_library/7) is [drupal_get_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_library/7), which is then called by [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7), the function that modules call to add a library during a page request. Until one of those functions is not called, `hook_library()` is not invoked.